# Using Mozilla's concatenating strings with delimiter example in Angular2+?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am wanting to concat an indeterminate amount of string arguments with a specified delimiter, so I Google'd the issue and came across a page on [Mozilla's website](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments#Defining_a_function_that_concatenates_several_strings) instructing on how to do just that using the `arguments` object.

```
function myConcat(separator) {
  var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1);
  return args.every(x => x === '') ? '' : args.join(separator);
}
```

When I tried this in a normal JS compiler such as [repl.it](https://repl.it/repls/BetterQuestionableDos), it worked perfectly! I couldn't be happier to have it proven, tried and tested.

However, when plugging the code into my Angular 6 app, I get the usual error stating that when calling the function, I am passing in too many arguments and that it only expects the one.

Is there anything I can do to get this working in Angular 6?

Comment: Have you tried using rest parameters instead of relying on the arguments object?

Comment: If I knew what that meant, I probably would have :-P

Comment: something like this function myConcat(separator, ...strings) { return strings.every(x => x === '') ? '' : strings.join(separator); }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might work if you use [rest parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters) instead of the arguments object:

```
function myConcat(separator, ...strings) {
 return strings.every(x => x === '') ? '' : strings.join(separator);
}
```

Comment: Aha! I'd been looking for how I could pass an arg along with a long arg!
I must have had it the wrong way around when I tried (...args, sep).

Comment: @physicsboy Yes, rest parameters have to be the last argument to a function.

Comment: I shall bear that in mind for future! Thanks for the help :-)